# PyTables install fail at windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, installation, hdf5, pytables

I try to install pytable module. I use win7 x64, python 2.7.2 (x32), cython 0.16, visual studio 2008 (9.0). At cmd.exe 'run as administrator' write: 'python setup.py install'.

But there are unresolved external symbols and build failed:

```
* Found numpy 1.6.2 package installed.
* Found numexpr 1.4.2 package installed.
* Found Cython 0.16 package installed.
* Found HDF5 headers at ``C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include``, library at ``C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\lib``.
* Could not find LZO 2 headers and library; disabling support for it.
* Could not find LZO 1 headers and library; disabling support for it.
* Could not find bzip2 headers and library; disabling support for it.
cythoning tables\linkExtension.pyx to tables\linkExtension.c
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
building 'tables.utilsExtension' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\PC" /Tctables\utilsExtension.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.obj -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\PC" /Tcsrc/utils.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/utils.obj -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\PC" /Tcsrc/H5ARRAY.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/H5ARRAY.obj -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\PC" /Tcsrc/H5ATTR.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/H5ATTR.obj -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\PC" /Tcblosc/blosc.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/blosc.obj -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\PC" /Tcblosc/blosclz.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/blosclz.obj -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\PC" /Tcblosc/shuffle.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/shuffle.obj -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_HDF5USEDLL_=1 -Iblosc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\PC" /Tcblosc/blosc_filter.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/blosc_filter.obj -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.9\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\libs" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\PCbuild" hdf5dll.lib /EXPORT:initutilsExtension build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/utils.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/H5ARRAY.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/H5ATTR.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/blosc.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/blosclz.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/shuffle.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/blosc_filter.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\tables\utilsExtension.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.pyd.manifest
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe
   Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.lib and object build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.exp
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_C_S1_g referenced in function ___pyx_pf_6tables_14utilsExtension_15AtomToHDF5Type
H5ATTR.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _H5T_C_S1_g
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_UNIX_D64BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_UNIX_D32BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_IEEE_F64BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _H5T_IEEE_F64BE_g
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_IEEE_F32BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _H5T_IEEE_F32BE_g
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_U64BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_U32BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_U16BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_U8BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_I64BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_I32BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_I16BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_I8BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_B8BE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_UNIX_D64LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_UNIX_D32LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_IEEE_F64LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _H5T_IEEE_F64LE_g
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_IEEE_F32LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _H5T_IEEE_F32LE_g
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_U64LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_U32LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_U16LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_U8LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_I64LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_I32LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_I16LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_I8LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
utilsExtension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5T_STD_B8LE_g referenced in function _initutilsExtension
H5ARRAY.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5P_CLS_DATASET_CREATE_g referenced in function _H5ARRAYmake
blosc_filter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5E_PLINE_g referenced in function _blosc_set_local
blosc_filter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5E_CALLBACK_g referenced in function _blosc_set_local
blosc_filter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5E_CANTREGISTER_g referenced in function _register_blosc
build\lib.win32-2.7\tables\utilsExtension.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 31 unresolved externals

error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.e
xe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\
1.8.9\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\libs" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program
Files (x86)\Python27\PCbuild" hdf5dll.lib /EXPORT:initutilsExtension build\temp.
win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/uti
ls.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/H5ARRAY.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
\src/H5ATTR.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/blosc.obj build\temp.win32-2.
7\Release\blosc/blosclz.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/shuffle.obj build
\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blosc/blosc_filter.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\tables\u
tilsExtension.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.lib
 /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\tables\utilsExtension.pyd.manifest"
failed with exit status 1120
```

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I must use shared version of hdf5 library. 
http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html (HDF5189-win32-vs10-shared.zip). NOT static!